# Coded UI C# - Localization doesn't work for my web automation

Tags: c#, localization, coded-ui-tests, resx

An external web application needs testing on many locales e.g. fr_FR. Unfortunately for some reason still I was not able to get this into working.

I created localised .resx files (e.g. Res_ErrorMsgs.fr-FR.resx) and set the CurrentUICulture to fr-FR, but the English string is always retrieved. Following 4 code blocks depcit few experiments I tried out. Nothing worked.

In other when the external application’s culture is “fr-FR”; CodedUI has to insert the test data (to the text boxes on the external application) from the respective RESX culture file (fr-FR) and perform the test. At the moment even though I try to change the culture on CodedUI (see the code below) it still reads the test data from the default “en-GB” RESX file.

Note: I'm scripting Coded UI via C# on Microsoft  VS Enterprise 2015 / Windows 8.1 / OS locale en_GB.

```
Code block 1
        ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Res_ErrorMsgs", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
        string str = resourceManager.GetString("Err_PayServiceFeeBlank", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
        MessageBox.Show(str);

Code block 2
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Res_ErrorMsgs", typeof(Res_ErrorMsgs).Assembly);
        string errMsg = String.Format("The current culture is {0}.\n{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name, rm.GetString("Err_PayServiceFeeBlank"));
        MessageBox.Show(errMsg);

Code block 3
        ResourceManager rm1 = new ResourceManager(typeof(CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Res_ErrorMsgs));
        MessageBox.Show(rm1.GetString("Err_PayServiceFeeBlank", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")));

Code block 4
        ResourceManager rm2 = new ResourceManager("CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Res_ErrorMsgs", typeof(Res_ErrorMsgs).Assembly);
        MessageBox.Show(rm2.GetString("Err_PayServiceFeeBlank", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the solution name (on the Solution Explorer at right hand 
   side) -> Add -> New Item -> This will open "Add New Item - Solution Items" dialog box.
2. Select "Test Settings" under "Installed" from the left hand pane.
3. Now select the "Test Settings" file from the middle pane and give a meaningful name and click Add button
4. This will open the "Test Settings" wizard
5. Select "Deployment" from the left hand pane (4th from top)
6. This will enable you to "Specify directories and files in addition to the target assemblies". To do that firstly check "Enable Deployment" checkbox.
7. Now navigate to your "Solution Directory" via windows explorer. i.e. This is the directory where you have the .csproj file located.
8. Now further navigate to bin/Debug folder. Inside the Debug folder create folders for the cultures (locales) you like to test. e.g "en-US", "fr-FR" etc.
9. Now comeback to the step where you stopped at the "Test Settings" Wizard.
10. Press the "Add Directory" button and browse to culture folders (one after another) you created in step 8 and add them here.
11. Now close the wizard.
12. Now navigate to test settings file via the windows explorer and open it via a text editor like notepad or notepad++. (Remember this file will have the extension .testsettings)
13. File will contain something similar to below

```html
<Deployment>
  <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTest_Solution\bin\Debug\fr-FR\" />
  <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTest_Solution\bin\Debug\en-US\" />
</Deployment>
```

14. Update that to the following

```html
<Deployment>
  <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTest_Solution\bin\Debug\fr-FR\" outputDirectory="fr-FR\" />
  <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTest_Solution\bin\Debug\en-US\" outputDirectory="en-US\" />
</Deployment>
```

15. Save and close the file.
16. Now on visual studio, go to Test -> Test Settings -> Select the Test Settings File. Browse for the test settings file and press Open.

17.) Finally in your coded ui test script add the following 2 lines of code. Remember "Resources" is the name of my RESX file and its located inside "RegressionTest_Solution -> Utility" folder. 
You can have your RESX file in a diffrent path. But make sure you reference to it correctly. The "language" is a variable which could hold what ever the current culture you going to test. e.g. "en-US"

```
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(language);
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("RegressionTest_Solution.Utility.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

18.) Above 2 liner code will enable to pick the culture and read the values from the correct culture file. For me default culture file is always Resources.RESX and US culture file i have is  Resources.en-US.resx. That too is created at "RegressionTest_Solution -> Utility" folder.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it would seem that the resource file cannot be found and it is defaulting back to the GB culture. Can you iterate the resources available to ensure it sees them correctly?

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
foreach (string s in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()) 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My test code lives in a Coded-UI project.

Web app (which I test) works for localisation. But I cannot get my Coded-UI test project to switch to the web application’s culture when a non “en-GB” culture (e.g. fr-FR) test is running. Above code depicts the effort I took to change the culture to “fr-FR”.

I’m not using VMs. I’m using a csv datasource on which all the locales are defined. In other words, iteratively the same test is run against different locales. (e.g. en-GB, fr-FR). There should be away to change the culture without changing machine's localisation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is NO requirement for CodedUI to change the external application’s culture. But the requirement is; when the external application’s culture is “fr-FR”; CodedUI has to insert the test data (to the text boxes on the external application) from the respective RESX culture file (fr-FR) and perform the test. At the moment even though I try to change the culture on CodedUI (see the code above) it still reads the test data from the default “en-GB” RESX file.

Comment: I have updated the question as requested. It seems the class Assembly does not have a method called GetManifestResourceNames(). I could see method names like GetExecutingAssembly().

Comment: Hi MPavlak, thank for the reply. well after the iteration I can only see the following `CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Greeting.resources` in the OutPut -> debug log. I cannot see an entry for  `CodedUI_Regression.Utility.Greeting.fr-FR.resources`. So what else should I do in additon to the code I have put in the description to make the fr-FR culture available?

Comment: @MarinoJayasuriya How are you including and embedding your resource files?

Comment: firstly thanks very much for your patience and all the quick responses. I found a way to do this. Seems the default .Net way of setting locals is not working for Coded UI. I had to create a TestSettings file by right clicking “Solution” under the solution explorer ->Add ->New Item -> Test Settings. Then selecting that by navigating to menu Test->Test Settings -> <Tick the settings file>. Finally modifing “Deployment” section of the test settings file to copy the DLL at runtime and paste it to the unique (time stamped) sub folder inside “Out” folder. Will answer in deatil later.